# KeystoneJS relationship type, limit available items by field value

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, keystonejs

Is it possible to limit available displayed options in a relationship type of KeystoneJS by specifying a value condition?

Basically, a model has two sets of array fields, instead of letting the admin user select any item from the field, I would like to restrict to only the items that are part of a specific collection _id.

Comment: This question is not clear enough. I don't understand what are you trying to do and what's the problem. Please explain more. And share  the code what you are already have to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly the feature you're looking for, but you can specify a `filter` option on the `Relationship` field as an object and it will filter results so only those that match are displayed.

Each property in the `filter` object should either be a value to match in the related schema, or it can be a dynamic value matching the value of another `path` in the schema (you prefix the path with a `:`).

For example:

**User Schema**

```
User.add({
    state: { type: Types.Select, options: 'enabled, disabled' }
});
```

**Post Schema**

```
// Only allow enabled users to be selected as the author
Post.add({
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', filter: { state: 'enabled' } }
});
```

Or for a dynamic example, imagine you have a `role` setting for both `Posts` and `Users`. You only want to match authors who have the same `role` as the `post`.

**User Schema**

```
User.add({
    userRole: { type: Types.Select, options: 'frontEnd, backEnd' }
});
```

**Post Schema**

```
Post.add({
    postRole: { type: Types.Select, options: 'frontEnd, backEnd' },
    // only allow users with the same role value as the post to be selected
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', filter: { userRole: ':postRole' } }
});
```

Note that this isn't actually implemented as back-end validation, it is just implemented in the Admin UI. So it's more of a usability enhancement than a restriction.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Jed's answer, I think the correct property (at least in the latest version of KeystoneJS 0.2.22) is 'filters' instead of 'filter'. 'filter' doesn't work for me.